# How transform string to readable time format in python?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, datetime-format

I have a dataset whit two colums, one for date in this format `20190313` and I convert to date time with this code:

```
import pandas as pd
from functools import reduce
pd.set_option("display.max_columns", 500)
df['Date_O'] = pd.to_datetime(df.Date_O)
```

This transform the string into: `2019-03-28`

but for the time column I have rows with nine characters like this: `130928487` and eight character rows like this: `91957277`.

How I can transform that column into a readable time format? I Tried already with datetime

Comment: Can you add `130928487` indicates which format?

Comment: That indicates the hour whit milisecons and I want to tansform to a H:M format

Answer (score 1):

To convert your string to datetime :

```
from datetime import datetime

# input : 130928487 means 13:09:28:487
input = "130928487"

date_time = datetime.strptime(input, "%H%M%S%f")

print("Date time:", date_time)
```

`Date time: 1900-01-01 13:09:28.487000`

```
d = date_time.strftime("%H:%M")
print("H:M format output:", d)
```

`H:M format ouput : 13:09`

Comment: my time columns isn't a timestamp is the hour without format

Comment: E.G. '130928487' means 13:09:28:487 and '91957277' means 9:19:57:277

Comment: OK, corrected with your comments. With this code, '91957277' gives '1900-01-01 09:19:57.277000' for date_time and '09:19' for H:M format.